# What thing comes next?

Tags: philosophy

Substance can store energy

[image]

This signifies the inanimate universe, planets and stars.

Substance and energy can store information

[image]

This signifies life and evolution.

Substance and energy and information can store worth (money):

[image]

[image]

This signifies the appearance of consciousness and society.

What comes next? What can money store?

Comment: I **hate** voting to close questions, but seriously, how is this question relevant to world building at all??

Comment: The first two steps are basic energy/matter duals.  Jumping to "substance/energy can store worth" is a bit trickier.  I think you could make a solid argument that substance+energy can store "anything in the universe, of which worth is just one concept."

Comment: @Anixx Wait...? No conciousness before money...? In my worldview dependance on money is somewhat the antithesis of conciousness.

Comment: The very machines debt is stored on will use it as a priority mechanism to hunt down humans after becoming self aware and automated. The matrix has us, there is no escape.

Comment: Not sure it would be on-topic there but there is a Philosophy SE

Answer (score 2):

Money can store the loyalty/subservience of human beings.

[image]

Comment: +1 for that! Also, money stores the _worth_ of things. Sort of a circular statement but ...

Comment: I amended the question.